# How to transfer XML file from MQ to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, blob, ibm-mq

How can I transfer XML file from IBM MQ to Azure storage Blob?

The requirement is we have IBM MQ .XML file is the input in the MQ.  How can we transfer file from MQ to Azure Blob.

Comment: You will need to write a bridge that can get XML messages from MQ queue and send them to Azure storage using Azure Storage APIs. There is Azure Java/.NET Storage SDK.

Comment: Thank you Shashi for your reply.  Please share any url /code shippet using dotnet or any tool using which we can transfer files.